# parameter passing to a shared object function

Tags: c, shared-libraries, parameter-passing

i have a c-application which should load a shared object at runtime and call an arbitrary function of the shared object. The shared object was build by the user and gave me the signature of his function.

```
 int func(int a, int b, double c)
```

i use dlopen to load the object and dlsym to get a function pointer to the shared object function. Now i have to pass the parameter to the function. I don't now the signature at compile time. Whats the best way to do it?
Is there any chance to check signature before i call function in my application?

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the [C/C++ function pointer tutorial](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html). It should answer all of your questions.

With regard to checking at runtime: No, you cannot check the signature for fit because C does not support [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_science)). dlsym() usually does not return a proper function pointer but a (void *) which you have to cast. Using arbitrary shared functions whose signature you do not know beforehand is a sign of a bad design. My advice would be to rethink the architecture.